# "Back-casting" a Time Series

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, arima, sas

[image]The problem I have is that i have a series of data (between 2000-2010) and i have another series (independant variable) which is available between 1980 and 2010. I need to backcast the value of the first series using the second series

The existing approach thats been done is to build an OLS model between the two levels and score it historically.

I don't think that is correct because both series are non stationary so I took the first difference of both to make them stationary. Then I tested for AR and MA terms and AR(2) is significant so I have a model with the difference of the second series and AR(2)

How do I now use this to backcast the values from 1980-2000? I am using SAS for this and I tried reversing the series and using the forecast option in the ARIMA function and it worked however is this conceptually correct to do? Doesnt this mean that i am saying that the value of my dependant variable series is dependant on its future values because of applying AR(2) on a reverse series. That is obviously not possible. Or am i missing something

Does anyone have any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Hi: That's not clear to me because how can you use an ARIMA model to predict another series ? If one series is supposed to predict the other, could you write down what you are doing for that part ? If that is understood, then maybe the rest of the question would be more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?

Comment: Hi, I cant share the actual data but I have inserted an image showing how the data is. Essentially my model is Y(t) = alpha + beta * X(t) + theta * AR(2) (i.e. Y(t-2). X(t) and Y(t) are stationary first order difference series. I want to back-populate the values of Y(t) using this model

Comment: @Manu: If I understand, you have all the $X_t$ from 1980-2010. So, can you not predict $Y_t$ and then use the predictions for the missing values ?